# Problems with reading CPLEX LP models from file in R by package 'lpSolveAPI'

Tags: cplex, r

As an R user, I'm trying to read a CPLEX LP model from file by using the *read.lp* function from package *lpSolveAPI*.
Here's the command line (from within RStudio):

```
lprec <- read.lp(filename="P01_a.lp",type = "lp")
```

I get this message:

```
Error in read.lp(filename = "P01_a.lp", type = "lp") :
could not interpret P01_a.lp as an lp file.
```

Could you please help me? There seems to be no examples out there.
I attach the LP file "P01_a.lp" in CPLEX format:

```
Minimize
  cost: 12q1 + 14q2 + 16q3 + 18q4 + 10r1 + 12r2 + 14r3 + 16r4 + 3s1 + 3s2 + 3s3 + 3s4
Subject To
  d1: q1 +r1 - s1 = 100
  d2: s1 + q2 + r2 - s2 = 200
  d3: s2 + q3 + r3 - s3 = 150
  d4: s3 + q4 + r4 - s4 = 400
  l1: q1 - 200b1 >= 0
  l2: q2 - 200b2 >= 0
  l3: q3 - 200b3 >= 0
  l4: q4 - 200b4 >= 0
  m1: r1 - 10000b1 <= 0
  m2: r2 - 10000b2 <= 0
  m3: r3 - 10000b3 <= 0
  m4: r4 - 10000b4 <= 0
Bounds
  0 <= q1 <= 200
  0 <= q2 <= 200
  0 <= q3 <= 200
  0 <= q4 <= 200
Binary
  b1
  b2
  b3
  b4
End
```

Here's my environment:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252  LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252    LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lpSolveAPI_5.5.2.0-17.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2  htmltools_0.5.0 tools_4.0.2     yaml_2.2.1      rmarkdown_2.3   knitr_1.29      
xfun_0.16      
 [8] digest_0.6.27   rlang_0.4.7     evaluate_0.14
```

Answer (score 3):

The first issue is that "LP" format means different things to lpsolve and CPLEX. See the warning about that near the top of the [lpsolve page](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/lp-format.htm) describing their format. There are [converters available](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/XLI.htm), but I don't know if there are any packaged for R. So you may need to install one and then convert the CPLEX .lp file to lpsolve format outside of R (or by making a system call from R).

A second issue is that lpsolve (or the lpsolveAPI package) is rather sensitive to white space. I tried copying a couple of examples from the lpsolve web pages, pasting them into text files, and then reading those text files into R. Something as trivial as an end-of-line character at the end of the last line of text (creating an empty final line) would trigger an error message. So good luck with that.